# Not every metric is induced from a norm

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces, examples-counterexamples

I have studied that every normed space $(V, \lVert\cdot \lVert)$ is a metric space with respect to distance function

$d(u,v) = \lVert u - v \rVert$, $u,v \in V$.

My question is whether every metric on a linear space can be induced by norm? I know answer is  no but I need proper justification.

Edit: Is there any method to check whether a given metric space is induced by norm ?

Thanks for help

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/38638/5798

Comment: @MattN. Thank you very much. That was helpful to me.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Let $V$ be a vector space over the field $\mathbb{F}$. A norm
$$\| \cdot \|: V \longrightarrow \mathbb{F}$$
on $V$ satisfies the homogeneity condition
$$\|ax\| = |a| \cdot \|x\|$$
for all $a \in \mathbb{F}$ and $x \in V$. So the metric
$$d: V \times V \longrightarrow \mathbb{F},$$
$$d(x,y) = \|x - y\|$$
defined by the norm is such that
$$d(ax,ay) = \|ax - ay\| = |a| \cdot \|x - y\| = |a| d(x,y)$$
for all $a \in \mathbb{F}$ and $x,y \in V$. This property is not satisfied by general metrics. For example, let $\delta$ be the discrete metric
$$\delta(x,y) = \begin{cases} 1, & x \neq y, \\ 0, & x = y. \end{cases}$$
Then $\delta$ clearly does not satisfy the homogeneity property of the a metric induced by a norm.

---

To answer your edit, call a metric
$$d: V \times V \longrightarrow \mathbb{F}$$
**homogeneous** if
$$d(ax, ay) = |a| d(x,y)$$
for all $a \in \mathbb{F}$ and $x,y \in V$, and **translation invariant** if
$$d(x + z, y + z) = d(x,y)$$
for all $x, y, z \in V$. Then a homogeneous, translation invariant metric $d$ can be used to define a norm $\| \cdot \|$ by
$$\|x\| = d(x,0)$$
for all $x \in V$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand now.

Comment: That is not enough as one needs to check that the so defined norm really induces the original metric and not another one: $d(\cdot,\cdot)\to\|\cdot\|\to d(\cdot,\cdot)$

Comment: This is an old post and it doesn't really matter much, but I have to be pedantic. So you say that if a metric comes from a norm on $\Bbb{R}$, then $d(ax,ay)=|a|d(x,y)$ but what if you just consider $\Bbb{R}$ as a vector space over $\{0,1\}$. Then the discrete metric IS homogeneous and translation invariant on this vector space.

Comment: Why does the metric *need* to be translation invariant? I understand that it needs to be homogeneous so it could even be considered a norm, but why should it have translation invariance?

Comment: @MichaelMunta If the metric is induced by a norm, then $d(x,y)=||x-y||$. So $d(x+z,y+z)=||(x+z)-(y+z)||=||x-y||=d(x,y)$.

Comment: You should clarify that your field $F$ is **normed**, otherwise the notation $|a|$ is meaningless.

Answer (score 29):

Here is another interesting example: Let $|x-y|$ denote the usual Euclidean distance between two real numbers $x$ and $y$. Let $d(x,y)=\min\{|x-y|,1\}$, the standard derived bounded metric. Now suppose we look at $\Bbb{R}$ as a vector space over itself and ask whether $d$ comes from any norm on $\Bbb{R}$. Then if there is such a norm say $||.||$, we must have the homogeneity condition: for any $\alpha \in \Bbb{R}$ and any $v \in \Bbb{R}$,

$$||\alpha v || = |\alpha| ||v||.$$

But now we have a problem: The metric $d$ is obviously bounded by $1$, but we can take $\alpha$ arbitrarily large so that $||.||$ is unbounded. It follows that $d$ does not come from any norm.

Comment: It was nice explanation to me. I had forgot to thank you. :)

Answer (score 20):

As Henry states above, metrics induced by a norm must be homogeneous. You can see that they must also be translation invariant: $d(x+a,y+a)= d(x,y).$ So any metric not satisfying either of those can not come from a norm.

On the other hand, it turns out that these two conditions on the metric are sufficient to define a norm that induces that metric: $d(x,0)=\| x \|.$

Comment: Thank you sir. I am fully satisfied with two answers given by you and Henry.:)

Comment: Did you mean instead that any **metric** not satisfying either of those can not come from a norm? And not the other way around? And also, these two conditions on the **metric** are sufficient to define a norm..?

Comment: @ThomasE. Sorry, you are right, I muddled up the words. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

Every homogeneous metric induces a norm via:
$$\|x\|:=d(x,0)$$
and every norm induces a homogeneous *and* translation-invariant metric:
$$d(x,y):=\|x-y\|$$

The clue herein lies in wether the induced norm really represents the metric as:
$$d(\cdot,\cdot)\to\|\cdot\|\to d(\cdot,\cdot)$$
which is the case *only* for the translation-invariant metrics:
$$d'(x,y)=d(x-y,0)=d(x,y)$$
whereas the induced metric *always* represents the norm as:
$$\|\cdot\|\to d(\cdot,\cdot)\to\|\cdot\|$$
as a simple check shows:
$$\|x\|'=\|x-0\|=\|x\|$$

Comment: @ Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 9):

**Personal Note:**

Good question, I remember wondering the same thing myself back when I new to real analysis.  Here's a counter example:

---

**Counter Example**

\begin{equation}
d(x,y):=I_{\{(x,x)\}}(x,y):=\begin{cases}
1 &:\,  \,x=y\\
0 &:\,  \,x\neq y.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
This is indeed a metric (check as an exercise).

Where $I_A$ is the indicator function of the set $A$; where here the set $(x,x)\in V\times V$.

If $r\in \mathbb{R}-\{0\}$, then $d(rx,ry)\in \{0,1\}$ hence $rd(x,y)\in \{0,r\}$ which is not in the range of $d:V\times V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

So, the metric $d$ fails the property that any metric induced by a norm must have, ie:
\begin{equation}
\mbox{it fails to have the property that: } \|rx-ry\|  =r\|x-y\|.
\end{equation}

---

**Interpretation & Some Intuition**:

The problem is that the topology is too fine, so all this topology can do is distinguish between things being the same or different.
As opposed to a norm topology which distinguised between object being, or not being on the same line (for some appropriate notion of line) (as well as them being different).

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. :)

Comment: Hi, is it correct to consider the metric d(x,y)=|x-y|^2018  that fails to h;ave the above property?

Comment: Yes, why not? :)

Answer (score 8):

One possible way of showing that a metric does **not** arise from a norm is to show that it is **bounded**, as it then **cannot be homogeneous**.

---

Proof:
Take $d$ a bounded metric on a space $X$: i.e. $\exists D \in \mathbb{R}_+$ such that $\forall (x,y) \in X^2, d(x,y) \leq D$. Suppose now for contradiction that $d$ arises from a norm, i.e. the exists a norm $ \|\cdot\|$ such that $d(x,y) = \|x - y\|$. Recall that the distance must then must be *homogeneous*, for we have $d(\lambda x, \lambda y) = \|\lambda x - \lambda y\| = |\lambda| \cdot \|x - y\| = |\lambda| d(x,y)$.

Take now  $(x_0, y_0) \in X\times X$ such that $d(x_0, y_0)\neq0$ , then we must have that $d\left( \frac{D+1}{d(x_0, y_0)} \cdot x_0, \frac{D+1}{d(x_0, y_0)} \cdot y_0 \right) = \frac{D+1}{d(x_0, y_0)} \cdot d(x_0, y_0) = D + 1 > D $ which contradicts the upper bound of the metric.