# A metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $d(\lambda x, \lambda y)=|\lambda| d(x,y)$ which is not induced by a norm

Tags: metric-spaces, normed-spaces, examples-counterexamples, pi

> Let $V=\mathbb{R}^n$.
>   Let $d:V \times V\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$.
>   Assume that for any $x,y\in V$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, we have $d(\lambda x, \lambda y) = |\lambda|d(x,y)$.
>   Is $d$ necessarily induced by a norm?

**Motivation**:  I've been thinking of $\pi$ and thought about why the ratio between a circles's circumference and its radius is constant. The proof is easy and is applicable to any norm. I think the "positive homogeneity" condition I posed on the metric above is enough for this ratio to be constant.

Comment: You _did_ note that this ratio is normally $2\pi$, not? Doesn't render the question invalid, just sayin'.

Comment: I did note that, thanks. I thought the formulation is clearer this way.

Comment: This might fail for a non translation invariant metric (i.e. $d(x+c, y+c) \neq d(x,y)$. Have you checked that?

Comment: Ah, answered just now by Lord Farin … ;)

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/166380/not-every-metric-is-induced-from-a-norm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is no. You need translational invariance as well; then it's a pretty well-known theorem (see e.g. [here](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Metric_Defines_Norm_iff_it_Preserves_Linear_Structure)).

As a counterexample when leaving out the translational invariance, consider:

$$d: \Bbb R^n \times \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R_{\ge 0}: d (x,y)=\begin{cases}
 \|x\|+\|y\| & \text{if $x \ne y$}\\
 0 & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$

This metric is sometimes referred to as the "metric of the French railway system", although there are similar metrics with the same name (cf. the comments).

Comment: but some of our trains do have intermediate stops !

Comment: I suppose it could also be called the "metric of the French intercity service system locally around Paris", but that's such a mouthful.

Comment: +1. I thought the SNCF distance $d$ was defined by $d(x,y)=\|x-y\|$ when $x$ and $y$ are colinear, and $d(x,y)=\|x\|+\|y\|$ otherwise. The intermediate stops again...

Comment: @did: Apparently multiple versions exist; they both work, whatever their name.

Comment: @did’s version is also called the [Paris metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hedgehog_space#Paris_metric). (I usually call it the *hedgehog metric*.)