# metric induced norm or norm induced metric

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

I am always confused between whether metric induces norm or norm induces metric. Can someone clarify this relation a bit for me? Was there any intuition on which direction being true?

Comment: Are you familiar with the definition of [_induce_](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/induce)?

Comment: A induces B if B can be obtained from A. We can obtain a metric from a norm. We usually can't obtain a norm from a metric.

Comment: Also see [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/423508/examples-of-metric-spaces-which-are-not-normed-linear-spaces)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a vector space, a norm can induce a metric.  For example, suppose that $u,v\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $||\cdot||$ be the Euclidean norm.  Then one can induce a metric $d(u,v):\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ given by

$$
d(u,v)=||u-v||. 
$$