# When a metric space is a normed space?

Tags: metric-spaces, normed-spaces

I'm trying to figure out that which condition should be provided for a metric space to be normed also?

Comment: Not exactly the same question, but related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/166380/not-every-metric-is-induced-from-a-norm

Comment: This post has some examples: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/423508/examples-of-metric-spaces-which-are-not-normed-linear-spaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the metric is induced from a norm.

This kind of metric space $(X,d)$ must satisfy
$$ d(x+a,y+a)=d(x,y)$$ 
$$ d(\alpha x,\alpha y)=|\alpha|d(x,y)$$ 
for all $x,y,a\in X$,and scalar $\alpha$.

And $X$ must be a vector space.