# Implications of inner products vs normed spaces vs metric spaces

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Is it true that:

-an inner product satisfies the properties of a norm if and only if the norm satisfies the parallelogram equality

-a norm can be induced by a metric if and only if the metric satisfies $d(x+a,y+a)=d(x,y)$ and $d(ax,ay)=ad(x,y)$

or are the implications one way?

Comment: And what do you think?

Comment: The wording seems to be a bit confused: The first statement should be something like, "a (vector space) norm is induced by an inner product iff it satisfies the parallelogram identity." In the second, a norm is a unary map $X \to \mathbb{R}$ but the notation here even indicates that a metric is a binary map $X \times X \to \mathbb{R}$, so a norm is never a metric---to ask a sensible question, we must first describe how to build a candidate metric in terms of a norm and/or vice versa.

Comment: sorry yes my wording for the 2nd part was poor. What i meant was a norm can be induced by a metric by setting ||x-y||=d(x,y) iff ...

Comment: And I'm thinking that these are indeed iff statements, though I've never seen them described this way, hence the question.

Comment: Your inner product lines still have the problem that Travis pointed out. $\;$

Comment: [Norms Induced by Inner Products and the Parallelogram Law](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21792/norms-induced-by-inner-products-and-the-parallelogram-law)

Comment: [Not every metric is induced from a norm](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/166380/not-every-metric-is-induced-from-a-norm), [When a metric space is a normed space?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/988770/when-a-metric-space-is-a-normed-space), [Was this metric induced by a norm?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/503542/was-this-metric-induced-by-a-norm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first statement is true both ways. Specifically, suppose $(X, ||\cdot||)$ is a normed linear space. Then the norm $||\cdot ||$ is induced by an
inner product iff the parallelogram law holds in $(X,||\cdot||)$.

For the second statement, this is not true. Call the condition $d(x,y)=d(x+a,y+a)$ translation invariance, and the condition $d(x,y)=d(ax,ay)$ homogeneity. Consider the following variant of the characteristic function 
$$
\chi(x,y)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
1, & x\neq y, \\ 
0, & \text{otherwise.} 
\end{matrix}\right.
$$
Homogeneity fails for $\chi,~x\neq y$. Indeed, 
$$
\chi(x,y)=1\neq a=\chi(ax,ay).
$$