# Is it possible to build a Banach space given a metric function space?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis

I have a curiosity,

For a given function space $V$, and a metric $d(\cdot,\cdot)$ is it possible to construct a non-empty subspace $W$ such that $(W,d)$ is a Banach space?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1326890/is-a-banach-space-also-a-metric-space

Comment: You can assume $d$ is induced by a norm $||\cdot||_V$

Comment: So $V$ is a normed space already? Then take any finite dimensional $W$ will do.

Comment: Because every finite dimensional space is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: @lukkio : Yes, for every finite dimension normed space, the norm is equivalent to the standard euclidean norm, so it is also complete.