# Metric space in which $d(x, y)\neq d(x - y, 0)$?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

When working in familiar metric spaces like $\mathbb{R}^n$ (with the Pythagorean distance function), it seems that $d(x, y) = d(x - y, 0)$ for all $x, y\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

Does this always hold in any metric space?

Comment: What's "$x-y$" in any metric space?

Comment: See [Not every metric is induced from a norm](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/166380/not-every-metric-is-induced-from-a-norm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Counter-example:**

Consider the British Rail metric on $\mathbb R$, given by $ d(x,y)=\lVert x\rVert +\lVert y\rVert $ for distinct points $x$ and $y$, and $d(x,x) = 0$. Then,

$$ d(2,1)=\lVert 2\rVert +\lVert 1\rVert = 3 \neq 1 = \lVert 2- 1\rVert +\lVert 0\rVert= d(2-1,0).$$

Answer (score 0):

No. There are metric spaces that haven't a "$0$" element. Consider this example:

Let $A$ be an arbitrary set (of whatever you want). Define in $A$ the function $d:A\times A \to [0,\infty[$ by
$$d(a,b)=\left\{\begin{array}{c} 0 & \text{if }a=b\\ 1 & \text{otherwise} \end{array}\right.$$
We can show that $(A,d)$ is a metric space.

Choose, for example, $A=\Bbb{N}$ or $A=C^{\infty}([0,1])$ or whatever and have fun.