# Metric on a linear space is induced by norm if and only if the metric is homogeneous and translation invariant

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces, examples-counterexamples

Could someone please help me prove that every metric on a linear space is induced by norm if and only if the metric is homogeneous and translation invariant? I found this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/166382/279147)   about homogeneity but I'm not sure how to extend this to every metric. Thank you.

Comment: If $d(x,y)$ is translation invariant then $d(x,y)=d(x-y,0)$. Define $\left\|x\right\|=d(x,0)$ and check that it is a norm: $\left\|x\right\|=d(x,0)=0$ iff $x=0$. $\left\|ax\right\|=d(ax,0)=d(ax,a0)=|a|d(x,0)=|a|\left\|x\right\|$. Finally, $\left|x+y\right|=d(x+y,0)=d(x,-y)\leq d(x,0)+d(0,-y)=d(x,0)+d(y,0)=\left\|x\right|+\left\|y\right\|$.

Comment: @orole: why post an answer in the comment section?