# prove that a metric induces a norm if it satisfies a given property

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

I was working through some exercises from a Functional Analysis book, and am stumped by a question which seems like it should be easy enough:

let $d$ be a metric on a vector space $E$, satisfying the following condition (1):
$$
\forall x,y \in E \hspace{5pt} \forall \lambda \in \mathbb{R} : d(x,x+\lambda y) = |\lambda|d(x,x+y) 
$$
prove that $\|x\| := d(x,0)$ defines a norm.

To prove this I already checked three of the four properties of a metric: trivially we have $\|x\| \geq 0$ for all $x$, with equality if and only if $x=0$. We can also see that

$$
\|\lambda x\| = d(\lambda x, 0) = d(0, 0+\lambda x) = |\lambda| d(x,0) = |\lambda|\|x\|
$$

as expected. However, I got stuck trying to prove that $\|x+y\| \leq \|x\| + \|y\|$, that is, proving that for a metric $d$ satisfying (1) we have $d(x+y,0) \leq d(x,0)+d(y,0)$.

I have searched this site as well as others for necessary conditions for a metric to induce a norm, hoping to find a similar proof. I did find that for a metric to induce a norm through $d(x,0)$, the metric must be translation invariant as well as homogeneous: see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/166380/not-every-metric-is-induced-from-a-norm/166382#166382). As such, these two conditions are necessary, but I am left wondering why they would be sufficient: one comment mentions that it 'turns out that these conditions are sufficient', but does not elaborate. Most of the other discussions here seem to be about [why these conditions are necessary](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2606889/metric-on-a-linear-space-is-induced-by-norm-if-and-only-if-the-metric-is-homogen), so further search didn't help me. Finally, when I am convinced that these conditions are actually sufficient, I would then still have to show that the condition given by the exercise implies homogeneity as well as translation invariance.

It feels like I am missing something obvious. Could someone help here?

Comment: To whoever found the duplicate post: thanks a lot, the feat of finding such an old post is almost as impressive as the proof in said post!