# Why is $d(x,0)$ not a norm?

Tags: functional-analysis

If $\|x\|$ is a norm, then we can define $d(x,y):=\|x-y\|$ and it will be a metric. Now, if $d$ is a metric, why is $\|x\|:= d(x,0)$ not a norm? I think it fail for the sub-linearity, but I don't see how.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider $$d(x,y)=\lvert x-y\rvert^3.$$ You can prove that this is a metric. However, if you define $\lVert x\rVert:=d(x,0),$ then in general, for $x\neq 0,$ we will have $$\lVert\alpha x\rVert\neq\lvert\alpha\rvert\lVert x\rVert,$$ with a few exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

Homogeneity is not verified for the discrete metric for example. You can check the answer at [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/166380/not-every-metric-is-induced-from-a-norm)

Answer (score 1):

Take for example $d$ as the [discrete distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_space), then for $x\not=0$ and $|\lambda|\not=0,1$, we
$$1=d(\lambda x,0)=\|\lambda x\|\not=|\lambda|\|x\|=|\lambda|d(x,0)=|\lambda|$$
and the [absolute homogeneity property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Definition) does not hold.