# Does every norm induce a metric and vice versa?

Tags: metric-spaces, normed-spaces

I am an undergraduate student and we have both linear algebra and metric space course in this semester.In linear algebra we studied norm and in metric spaces we studied metric.Now studying some examples I think every metric on vector space may define a norm and every norm can define a metric.I am sure about the last one but does every metric on vector space give rise to a norm?

Comment: Norms can be used to define metrics. The most common way is by defining $d(x,y)=\|x-y\|$, which is called *the induced metric*. On the other hand, if $d$ is a metric on a vector space, there doesn't need to be a norm that satisfies the previous equation. Note that one necessary condition would be that $d(x+z,y+z)=\|(x+z)-(y+z)\|=\|x-y\|=d(x,y)$ implies that the metric needs to be translation invariant. So, any metric that is not translation invariant will not have a norm such that $d(x,y)=\|x-y\|$. For example, on $\mathbb{R}$ define $d(x,y)=|\arctan(x)-\arctan(y)|$.

Comment: Google "metric which is not a norm"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Not every metric is induced from a norm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/166380/not-every-metric-is-induced-from-a-norm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there are metrics that are not equivalent to a norm.  A [Fréchet space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_space) is a vector space with a translation-invariant metric that makes the space complete and locally convex.
There are Fréchet spaces that do not have a norm equivalent to the metric.  An example
is $\mathbb R^\omega$, the space of all real-valued sequences, where you can take the
metric to be $$d(x, y) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n} \frac{|x_n - y_n|}{1 + |x_n - y_n|}$$