# Does any homogeneous metric $d$ on a (real) vector space $V$ induce a norm via the map $v\to d(v,0)$ (without assuming $d$ is translation invariant)?

Tags: normed-spaces

Apologies in advance: I am new to math.stackexchange and do not know how to properly link.

It is well known that a norm $||\cdot||$ on a vector space $V$ induces a translation invariant, homogeneous metric $d$ on $V$ via $d(x,y) = ||x-y||$.

Conversely, it is easy to show that a translation invariant, homogeneous metric $d$ on a (real) vector space $V$ induces a norm via the map $v\to d(v,0)$.

In their reply to [Not every metric is induced from a norm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/166380/not-every-metric-is-induced-from-a-norm) , the user C-Star-W-Star [user:79762] states:

"Every homogeneous metric induces a norm via:
\begin{equation}||x|| := d(x,0).
\end{equation}

C-Star-W-Star then shows that the metric induced by this norm is the original metric only if the original metric is translation invariant.

My question: How can one show the triangle inequality holds for this $||x||$ without assuming that $d$ is translation invariant?

Comment: I think there is no way to avoid "translation invariant " property of the metric to prove the triangle inequality of norm.

Comment: I am grateful for this comment. I spent a good portion of my day trying to prove it without success. Of course this, by itself, means nothing, but I am happy to have you suggest that it is not possible!