# Distance that comes from a norm

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

In a certain proposition, I am given a distance function in a vector space ($d : \mathbb{V} \times \mathbb{V} \rightarrow \mathbb{V}$) that satisfies the following conditions:

$\forall \lambda \in \mathbb{R},d(\lambda x,\lambda y) = |\lambda|d(x,y) $

$\forall x,y,z \in \mathbb{R},d(x+z,y+z) = d(x,y) $

I am asked to prove that there exists a norm over $\mathbb{V}$ that satisfies $d(x,y) = ||x-y||$. My attempt would be assuming that there is no such norm and ending up with a contradiction with the definition of this distance. However, I actually do not know why there would be a function like that. I mean, the existence of a norm implies the existence of a distance, but the reciprocal is not always true. However, I get stuck in proving that in this case it is true.

Comment: $d(x,y) = \|x - y\|$ implies that $\|x\| = d(x,0)$. Try taking the latter equality as the definition of the norm. Can you check it satisfies the needed properties?

Comment: I tried that, but why would a function like that exists?

Comment: @DanielC. ... because you **define** it to be that?

Comment: I think your question is answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/166380/42969

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If such a norm exists, then for every $x\in \mathbb V$, you will have $$d(x, 0)=\|x-0\|=\|x\|$$

so this already uniquely defines what the only possible candidate for a norm can be. Now all you are left to do is to either prove that that candidate **is** indeed a norm, or prove that it is not.

Comment: Perfect, now proving that is a norm is straightforward