# Are these conditions also sufficient for a metric to be induced by a norm?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space such that the set $X$ is also a vector space over the field $\mathbb{R}$ of real numbers or the field $\mathbb{C}$ of complex numbers. Then the following holds:

> If the metirc $d$ is induced by a norm on $X$, then we must have 
>   $$d(u+x,u+y) = d(x,y) \ \mbox{ for all } \ u, x, y \in X,$$
>   and 
>   $$d(\alpha x, \alpha y ) = \vert \alpha \vert \cdot d(x,y) \ \mbox{ for all } \ x, y \in X \ \mbox{ and for all scalars } \ \alpha.$$

Are the above conditions sufficient also for the metric $d$ to be induced by a norm?

Comment: Related (duplicate?): [Metric induced by a norm - what conditions should this metric meet?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/510924/metric-induced-by-a-norm-what-conditions-should-this-metric-meet) (BTW it was shown among the list of related questions in the sidebar.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Define $\|x\|$ to be $d(0,x)$. This is a norm (that induces $d$).

Answer (score 4):

The answer here is yes.  Define $\|x\| = d(0,x)$.  We have:

- $\|0\| = d(0,0) = 0$
- $\|x+y\| = d(0,x+y) \leq d(0,x) + d(x,x+y) = d(0,x) + d(0,y) = \|x\| + \|y\|$
- For a scalar $\alpha$, we have
  $\|\alpha x\| = d(0,\alpha x) 
  = |\alpha| \cdot d(0,x) = |\alpha| \cdot \|x\|$

Comment: Probably it's just me, but I'd clarify that trinagle inequality comes from $d(0,x+y)\le d(0,x)+d(x,x+y)=d(0,x)+d(0,y)$ by first condition (this didn't come immediately obvious).

Comment: @user160738 thanks for the feedback

Comment: @Omnomnomnom how do we obtain $d(x,x+y) \leq d(0,y)$? Oh I get it! $d(x,x+y) = d(x+0,x+y)= d(0,y)$. Right?

Comment: Right ${}{}{}{}$