# Norms in $\mathbb R^2$ - Strategy to prove that a norm is a norm on a set.

Tags: normed-spaces

What points should I prove when I am asked to prove that a particular norm, say $||\mathbf x||=||(x,y)||=(|x|^{1/2}+|y|^{1/2})^2$, is a norm in $\mathbb R^2$?

*P.S* I have read about the difference between a *metric* and a *norm* (Please refer to the answers to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38634/difference-between-metric-and-norm-made-concrete-the-case-of-euclid)).

Here I have deliberately used the term norm instead of metrics; is it a mistake in this particular case? I have written the question this way because it is exactly what I read in a past math exam that I'm studying.

Thank you.

Comment: you should check the definition of norm. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_%28mathematics%29.

Comment: @Babgen Ok, so I need to verify absolute homogeneity, positivity, triangle inequality and the zero vector. What about my use of the term _norm_ in the question? Is it correct? Should I have used the term _metric_?

Comment: Yes, It is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following statement:

$1$.Absolute homogeneity: $||ax||=a||x||$, for $a\in \mathbb R$ and $x\in \mathbb R^2$.

$2$.Triangle inequality: $||x+y||\leq ||x||+||y||$.

$3$.Separates points: If $||x||=0$ then $x$ is the zero vector.

For Triangle inequality:
$||(2,2)+(1,3)||=16$ but $||(2,2)||+||(1,3)||=15.71$. This cant be a norm.

Comment: I was reviewing this answer. How should I prove that the triangle inequality does not hold here without plugging some numbers in $||\mathbf x + \mathbf y||$? Should I use algebra to find a contradiction?