# An example of a norm which can't be generated by an inner product

Tags: examples-counterexamples, normed-spaces, inner-products

I realize that every inner product defined on a vector space can give rise to a norm on that space.  The converse, apparently is not true.  I'd like an example of a norm which no inner product can generate.

Comment: You may be interested in having a look at the the threads: "[Connections between metrics, norms and scalar products (for understanding e.g. Banach and Hilbert spaces)](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/38460/5363)" (containing a slightly more advanced perspective on your question) and "[Norms Induced by Inner Products and the Parallelogram Law](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/21792/5363)" (an outline and a detailed solution to the exercise "if a norm satisfies the parallelogram law then it's an inner product" suggested by Qiaochu in the comments).

Answer (score 45):

For example, any $p$-norm except the $2$-norm.

To check this, any norm obtained from the inner-product should satisfy the [parallelogram law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law). Whereas the $p$-norm with $p \neq 2$, does not satisfy the parallelogram law.

Comment: And conversely, any norm satisfying the parallelogram law comes from an inner product. This is a nice exercise.

Comment: The "nice exercise" that Qiaochu referred to is often called the "[polarisation identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity)".

Comment: Wow, this is quite remarkable! I was wondering why it was hard to find which inner product induces L3, L4 etc. norms and we simply have that *every* $p$ norm except L2 cannot be induced!

Answer (score 3):

The norm on C[a,b] defined by ||f||=sup{|f(t)|: t belongs to [a,b]} does not satisfy the parallelogram law. take f(t)=1 and g(t)=t-a/b-a 0r f(t)=max{sin t, 0} and g(t)=max{-sin t, 0) on [0, 2pi].

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).