# Is any norm induced by some inner product?

Tags: normed-spaces, inner-products

It is a well-know fact that an inner product induces some norm.

How about the converse? I think it's false but I can't think of an example.

I'm thinking some properties like the parallelogram law will not hold with any norm...

Comment: You have many norms which are induced by some function, some by inner product and many which are not induced at all. $l_p$, if $p\ne 2$ is not an induced norm at all.

Comment: Duplicate of [the third item in the "Related" section](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159766/an-example-of-a-norm-which-cant-be-generated-by-an-inner-product). See also [the first item in the "Related" section](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21792/norms-induced-by-inner-products-and-the-parallelogram-law?rq=1).

Comment: In fact, every $p$ norm, $p \not = 2$, cannot be induced by an inner product!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good thought with the parallelogram law.  In fact, a norm will satisfy the parallelogram law *if and only if* it can be induced by some inner product.  Given a norm satisfying the parallelogram law, we can recover the inner product inducing that norm using the [polarization identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity).

Some common examples: the $p-$norm given by $\|x\|_p = \left(\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|^p\right)^{1/p}$) is a norm for any $p \geq 1$, but will only satisfy the parallelogram law for $p=2$.

Another important example of a norm that doesn't obey the parallelogram law is the "$\infty$-norm" given by $\|x\|_{\infty} = \max_i\{|x_i|\}$.

Answer (score 1):

In inner product spaces, you have the equality
$$||x+y||^2+||x-y||^2 = 2(||x||^2+||y||^2).$$
This equality can easily be shown by writing $\langle x,x\rangle$ for $||x||^2$.

In general, this does not hold. See the space $\mathbb R^2$ with the norm $||(x,y)||=\max\{|x|,|y|\}$.

Comment: Provide an example please.

Comment: Take any norm for $\mathbb R^2$ such that the unit ball is not an ellipse.

Comment: @GabrielR. example added.

Answer (score -2):

Of course, the norm on $\mathbb{R}^2$ given by $\|(x,y)\|=(|x|^{3.63421}+|y|^{3.63421})^{1/3.63421}$, where $|{\cdot}|$ denotes the absolute value, is not induced by any inner product, still it is a norm.

Comment: No, that is not a norm, as it does not respect the multiplication by scalars.

Comment: See comment by Tobias, this is indeed not a norm.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Sorry, I was a bit too short-headed.