# We have the scalar product $\left \langle \cdot, \cdot \right \rangle$. How is its belonging norm $\left \| \cdot \right \|$ defined?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, definition, normed-spaces

We have the scalar product $\left \langle \cdot, \cdot \right \rangle$. How is its belonging norm $\left \| \cdot \right \|$ defined?

I'm not sure if I got it correctly because these dots are confusing. They just stand for "any", like variables $x,y$ as example?

If so I think they are just asking for the axioms of a norm?

Let $V$ be a $K$ vector space for $\left\{\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C}\right\}$. A non-negative real function $\left \| \cdot \right \|: V \rightarrow [0, \infty )$ is called norm, if it has following properties:

1. positivity: $\left \| a \right \| \geq 0 \forall a \in V$ and $\left \| a \right \| >0 \forall a \in V$ with $a \neq 0$
2. homogeneity: $\left \| ka \right \| = |k| \cdot \left \| a \right \| \forall a \in V, k \in K$
3. triangle inequality: $\left \| a+b \right \| \leq \left \| a \right \|+\left \| b \right \| \forall a,b \in V$

**Edit: Or would this even be better, and shorter:**

Let $V$ be a $K$ vector space with a scalar product $\left \langle \cdot, \cdot \right \rangle$ whereby $K \in \left\{R, C\right\}$. Then there is a norm $\left \| \cdot \right \|$ on $V$ defined by

$$\left \| a \right \| = \sqrt{\left \langle a,a \right \rangle}, a \in V$$

Is that what was asked for? Please help me, this is not homework.

Comment: Yes, the dots are placeholders for variables. The norm ||x|| is just the inner product <x, x>.

Comment: I think you could start with the 5 properties of inner product, and arrive at it being a norm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The dots play kind of the role of a placeholder. We simply write $\|\cdot\|$ instead of
\begin{align*}
V&\to\mathbb{R}\\
v&\mapsto \|v\|
\end{align*}

and $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ instead of
\begin{align*}
V\times V&\to\mathbb{R}\\
(u,v)&\mapsto\langle u,v\rangle
\end{align*}

Whenever $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is an inner product on a vector space $V$, the norm $\|\cdot\|$ on $V$ induced by the inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is defined by:

\begin{align*}
V&\to\mathbb{R}\\
v&\mapsto\|v\|=\sqrt{\langle v,v\rangle}
\end{align*}

Now, as you said, you should show that the "norm" we just defined is indeed a norm on $V$, which means that it satisfies the 3 properties that you gave.

Comment: Maybe a square root missing?

Comment: @SpettroDiA Oh my bad! Yes, you're right!

Comment: Is my edit alright now, does it answer the task? Tried to use your answer for it.

Comment: @tenepolis Yes that's right. Just a better way to say it: "the map $v\mapsto\sqrt{\langle v,v\rangle}$ is a norm on $V$.

Comment: Well, the three conditions mean that this map is indeed a norm. The first part means that this isn't any arbitrary norm: it is a norm associated to the inner product on your space in a nice way, for example you can prove that for this norm: $\|u+v\|^2=\|u\|^2+\|v\|^2+2\Re{\langle u,v\rangle}$ (where $\Re$ denoted the real part; just a precaution if you're working on a complex vector pace). Another arbitrary norm may not relate to your inner product like that...

Comment: ... In fact, [there are some inner products that are not induced by any norm](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159766/an-example-of-a-norm-which-cant-be-generated-by-an-inner-product).

Comment: @tenepolis You didn't [accept](https://img.clipartfest.com/2d922d62c2520573a621ed7317479fe7_dark-green-check-mark-clip-art-green-check-mark-clipart_640-480.svg) my answer. This normally means that you're not satisfied by my answer, or that it is incomplete. If that's the case, would you tell me what do you still not understand?

Comment: Actually I did accept it, but I guess there are some bugs on phone or something. Accepted on computer now ^^

Comment: @tenepolis Oh I see. Glad it was useful :)