# A normed linear space is need not be inner product space.

Tags: functional-analysis, examples-counterexamples, normed-spaces, inner-products

Can anyone give a simple example for it? [![enter image description here][1]][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3KiB.jpg . Please expalin the example shown in pic.

Comment: But you've already got the example marked in yellow in your image?!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An example of a norm which can't be generated by an inner product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159766/an-example-of-a-norm-which-cant-be-generated-by-an-inner-product)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have written down is that a normed linear space is an inner product space if and only if the [parallelogram law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law#Normed_vector_spaces_satisfying_the_parallelogram_law) holds.  For a simple example of a normed spaced that is not an inner product space, consider the space of real-valued continuous functions on $[0,1],$ with norm $$\|f\|=\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)|$$  It is easy to see that this is a real vector space and to verify that $\|\cdot\|$ is a norm.

To see that it is not an inner product space we just need one example where the parallelogram law fails.  Take $f(x)=x,\ g(x)=x^2.$  Then $\|f\|=\|g\|=1,\ \|f+g\|=2,\ \|f-g\|=1/4,$ and one can check that the parallelogram law does not hold.