# Does Norm imply Inner Product? If not, what's a counter-example?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm currently working my way through the book "Linear Algebra Done Right" by Sheldon Axler.

In the book, he defines a norm the following way.

> Let $V$ be an inner product space and let $\langle u, v\rangle$ denote the inner product of $u$ and $v$. Then, the **Norm** of any vector $v \in V$ is defined as $||v|| = \sqrt{\langle v, v\rangle}$.

However, I was digging through Wikipedia and I discovered the concept of a "Normed Vector Space", i.e. a vector space on which a norm is defined. Inner product spaces seemingly constitute a subset of normed vector spaces.

My question is this - how is it possible to have a normed vector space that is not an inner product space if it seems like the definition of a norm depends on the presence of an inner product?

Comment: The definition of the norm of a normed space does not depend on an inner product. You can find it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normed_vector_space). Given an inner product space you *can* define *a* norm the way you quoted; that is, a function satisfying the definition of the norm of a normed space.

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law#Normed_vector_spaces_satisfying_the_parallelogram_law) may also be of interest.

Comment: Look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159766/an-example-of-a-norm-which-cant-be-generated-by-an-inner-product

Answer (score 0):

Not quite. If we have an inner product, ee can use it to define a norm. But there are norms that are induced by no inner product. For instance,$$\|(x,y)\|=|x|+|y|.$$