# Dot Product vs. Product of Norms

Tags: euclidean-geometry

I was working on an algebraic proof for the [Triangle Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality) when I came across an instance in which $$(a \cdot b) \le ||a|| \cdot ||b||$$ Is this true in general, or was this just a special case? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Search the net (or MSE) for Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Right, of course! I somehow completely forgot that, despite it being the reason for me working on this in the first place lol thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It is the Cauchy-Schwarz (CS) ineq. as Kavi points out. Since you mention proving the triangle ineq., I will also point out a few things:

CS holds in any inner product space.

The triangle ineq. holds for any normed vector space; in fact, it is a *defining feature* of a norm.

Using CS to show the triangle ineq. actually explains why any inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ *induces* a valid norm defined by

$$\|x\|\equiv \sqrt{\langle x,x \rangle}.$$

Indeed, any inner product space is always a normed space with the norm thus defined, but the converse is not true.  There are norms [not induced by inner products](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159766/an-example-of-a-norm-which-cant-be-generated-by-an-inner-product) (e.g. any $p$ norm, $p\neq 2$). A proof of the triangle inequality using CS would thus not apply for such cases.